# Wht is the difference between device-width and max-device-with?

Tags: css, media-queries

According to W3C [The ‘device-width’ media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width)

```
@media all and (max-device-width : 480px)
@media all and (device-width : 480px)
```

is there any difference between these two ?

If `device-width` is the width of the rendering surface and why there is a `max-device-width` ?

`max-device-width/min-device-width` is the Maximum/minimum possible width of a device ,

so whts is its exact difference between `device-width` and when device-width when used without prefix ?

Answer (score 2):

The condition `device-width : 480px` means that the width of the device is *exactly* 480 pixels. The condition `max-device-width : 480px` means that the width of the device is *at most* 480 pixels, i.e. it is 480 pixels or less.

This can be confusing, but they wanted to define media query syntax so that it uses the general syntax of CSS declarations, i.e. *property*: *value*, not e.g. *property* <= *value*. So you can think of `max-device-width` as a kind of pseudo-property and read `max-device-width : 480px` as “device width is at maximally 480px” rather than in terms of “maximum device width”.